# What is the force carrier for neutrons in fission?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, strong-force, carrier-particles, pions

Say I have a neutron capture event, leading to a fission reaction in which a few neutrons are expelled. These neutrons inherit a certain momentum from this fission reaction.

How do these neutrons obtain that momentum? Is there some kind of electromagnetic interaction between the nucleus and the neutron’s dipole moment? Or are there different interactions at play here?

Comment: Strong interactions or ("nuclear") forces. What keeps the nucleus together is what is disturbed.

Comment: @CosmasZachos But isn’t the strong force attractive (for almost all distances)? So why is it expelled then? Or is it the neutron pushed to a region where the strong force is repulsive?

Comment: Isn't the very fact that there were two fission fragments better bound and they are flying away, living proof that their [mutual attraction is overcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission), too? You have a roiling chaos with attraction and energy imbalances producing the outcome.

Comment: I agree on that - I know that the binding energy per nucleon is less for the fragments than for the fissile nucleon. But the conclusion that the gluon, the strong force carrier, imparts the momentum on the neutron is what I do not understand. How does it do that?

Comment: How does a neutron scatter off a nucleus? How does inelastic neutron scattering work? How does a (n,p) or (p,n) reaction occur? Clearly there is an interaction force.

Comment: OK, that's your misconception: you are thinking gluons. ***No direct gluons here***. The nuclear forces involved in these nuclear reactions are residual, involving pions, other mesons, effective nuclear potentials, anything but gluons, which are the building blocks, but you don't get to see them at such "low" energies/ "long" distances , on the scale of a single hadron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that the force carriers are [mostly pions](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/hadron.html), but the details get quite complicated.

In physics we know about four fundamental interactions: the strong force, the electromagnetic force, the weak force, and gravitation.  The neutron participates in all of them, but feebly.  Its gravitational mass is small, it has no electric charge, and its magnetic moment is smaller than the magnetic moment of the electron by [approximately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magneton) the ratio of the electron and neutron masses --- that kills the long-range $1/r^2$ forces.  The strong and weak forces are both contact interactions with finite range, but the strong force is ... stronger.  So when a neutron is near enough to a nucleus to undergo scattering, including only the strong interaction is usually a pretty good approximation.

Microscopically, the strong interaction is an interaction between color charges, mediated by gluons.  However at the low energies involved in nuclear fission, quarks and gluons are not the degrees of freedom which give the most parsimonious explanations of what's happening in [QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics).  Instead, the QCD vacuum condenses into color singlet states like the proton and neutron, which interact by exchanging [color-singlet mesons](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/listings/contents_listings.html) like the pion, the rho, the omega, and others.  These mesons effectively give the nucleons a set of [Yukawa interaction potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) which are exponential in the meson masses, so the lightest meson (the pion) contributes the most to the interaction except at very short distances.

Comment: I suspect that the issue troubling Herrn Mackenbach is not the force carrier, but rather: *Why don't the neutrons stick to the two large fission fragments given that the nuclear force is attractive?*

Comment: The answer there is energy conservation, but that's not in the current version of the question.